# How to set up a tiered promo codes

Tags: promotions

I want to set up a promotion specifically for customers to purchase products that fall under one specific category listed on our website (we'll call it category A).

Buy 1 product in category A, get 10% off
Buy 2 products in category A, get 15% off
Buy 3 products in category A, get 20% off

I want this set up so that a customer has to have 1 product from that entire category in their cart to get the promo, not so they can have a quantity of 1 and include multiple products from that category in their order and get 10% off. If they have 2 products from that category in their cart (or 2 of the same product), then they would be bumped up to the next tier and get 15% off. I can't figure out how to set this up in Magento so it works how I want it to.